# Fancybox not loading image from external URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Working HTML code:

```
<a class="fancybox-gallery" href="http://sale.coupsoft.com/uploads/938218/logo.png">
    <img class="animate scale animated" src="http://sale.coupsoft.com/uploads/938218/logo.png" alt="Image1">
    <div class="image-hover">
        <i class="icon-zoom-in-2"></i>
    </div>
</a>
```

Failing HTML code:

```
<a class="fancybox-gallery" href="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg">
    <img class="animate scale animated" src="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg" alt="Image1" style="height:75px">
    <div class="image-hover">    
        <i class="icon-zoom-in-2"></i>
    </div>
</a>
```

When I tried to load the image from my website than it successfully executed but when I tried to load the image from external URL the fancybox is redirecting to that URL. How can I resolve this issue, and why is it happening?

Comment: Actually, nothing will load your image. Because of the `&#10;` at the end of the url to your image.

Comment: May be they don't allow hot-linking images.

Answer (score 1):

Check my working code on both of your cases.

And a [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/fz98sn11/).

```js
$("a.fancybox-gallery").fancybox({
  'transitionIn': 'elastic',
  'transitionOut': 'elastic',
  'speedIn': 600,
  'speedOut': 200,
  'overlayShow': false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />

<a class="fancybox-gallery" href="http://sale.coupsoft.com/uploads/938218/logo.png">
  <img class="animate scale animated" src="http://sale.coupsoft.com/uploads/938218/logo.png" alt="Image1">
  <div class="image-hover">
    <i class="icon-zoom-in-2"></i>
  </div>
</a>

<a class="fancybox-gallery" href="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg">
  <img class="animate scale animated" src="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg" alt="Image1" style="height:75px">
  <div class="image-hover">
    <i class="icon-zoom-in-2"></i>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because Fancybox isn't recognising that the link is pointing to an image, because the URL doesn't end with a `.jpg` (or any other image type).

To fix this, simply remove the `&#10;` from the end of the URLs:

```
<a class="fancybox-gallery" href="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg">
    <img class="animate scale animated" src="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg" alt="Image1" style="height: 75px">
    <div class="image-hover">    
        <i class="icon-zoom-in-2"></i>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: it not working another option take a look at edited question

Comment: Are you sure that the external website you're using allows linking from third party sources? Have you tried hosting the image on your own site? Ethically, this is what you should be doing anyway, otherwise you're just leeching someone else's bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `; (Semicolon)` From URL :

```
<a class="fancybox-gallery" href="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg&#10;">
    <img class="animate scale animated" src="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg&#10;" alt="Image1" style="height:75px">
    <div class="image-hover">    
        <i class="icon-zoom-in-2"></i>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: it not working another option take a look at edited question